# Backing up Windows hard drive under Linux OS?

Tags: linux, windows, backup

I use a dual-boot Linux/Windows machine, each having a separate 1TB SSD drive. Mostly Linux is used, Windows just occasionally.

An incremental daily/weekly/monthly backup using [rsnapshot](https://rsnapshot.org/) is set-up on the Linux. Backed up files are stored on the local NAS storage.

Does it make sense to mount Windows SSD drive under Linux and include it in the backup too? Are there serious drawbacks? I am having a hard time finding a decent incremental backup tool for Windows, so it would be nice to do it all at once.

Answer (score 0):

> Does it make sense to mount Windows SSD drive under Linux and include it in the backup too?

Why not?

> Are there serious drawbacks?

Yeah, under Linux you won't be able to access and properly store/restore NTFS ACL permissions.

> I am having a hard time finding a decent incremental backup tool for Windows, so it would be nice to do it all at once.

You could just backup certain directories, e.g. C:\Users\User\Documents instead of creating a backup of the entire drive. Windows works better and faster when you install it from scratch anyways.

Comment: Thanks. If I am not able to restore NTFS ACL permissions, what does that mean more preciselly, in practice? Should I care?

Comment: If you restore an entire NTFS partition under Linux it might not boot due to broken permissions.

Comment: OK, I can live with that. My main goal is just to save files.

Comment: For backing files up permissions are normally redundant.

Comment: it does a full backup, not an incremental, but have you taken a look at "clonezilla"? https://packages.ubuntu.com/hirsute/clonezilla